# Member pointers or reference arguments?

Tags: c++, coding-style

I have the following problem.

I got a class `PluginLoader` which oversees loading of plugins. It divides sub-stages of work to other classes like `Plugin`. `Plugin` calls functions of `PluginLoader` in its processing. Let's call that function `AddData`. Here, `PluginLoader` has to check if the data it receives is duplicate. For that, it uses a `ConflictResolver` class. Now, my problem is how to make an object of `ConflictResolver` available to `PluginLoader`. There are 3 ways I see out of this.

1. Use a `ConflictResolverFactory` class and create an object of `ConflictResolver` for `PluginLoader`.
2. Pass a constructed `ConflictResolver*` to the `PluginLoader` via its constructor or a member function `SetConflictResolver` and store it in a member variable and use it later. Both ways have drawbacks. If I pass it in the constructor, I will have to throw if the pointer is `NULL`. And I can't use exceptions as it is the custom here. If I pass it via `SetConflictResolver`, there is no way that I can guarantee that that function will be actually called by the user. Or I will have to check whether the member `ConflictResolver*` is `NULL` everywhere I use it.
3. Pass a `ConflictResolver &` to `PluginLoader`s `Load` method where all the work will be done. In turn, `Plugin`s Load method has to accept a `ConflictResolver &` as well (though it  has no use for it) and pass that back to `AddData` where `PluginLoader` will be able to use it.

Third method is safer compared to second. However, I have to pass around a reference even when it is not used.

If the first method cannot be used, what is the best way to do this?

Apologies for the wall :wq!

Comment: Is there going to be different types of `ConflictResolver`?

Comment: Is it that some top-level code calls `PluginLoader::Load()`, which calls `Plugin::Load()`, which calls `PluginLoader::AddData()`, which calls some method in `ConflictResolver`?

Comment: But each `PluginLoader` instance will have only one, unchanging `ConflictResolver` object associated with it, correct?  (I.e. it is not the case that different `Plugin` objects may need to ask `PluginLoader` to use different `ConflictResolver` objects?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass a ConflictResolver& to the PluginLoader constructor. You can now guarantee that the object is not null.

Comment: No, store the reference. You can declare member variables to be references.